# Select tensor slice along a dimension based on index

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a PyTorch tensor of the following shape: (100, 5, 100). I need to convert it into a tensor of shape (100, 100) by selecting from each row only one item in the second dimension, meaning that of those 5 elements I only need one, with its corresponding 100 elements.

To do this operation I have a second tensor of shape (100,) with the indices that specify which of those 5 items should be selected in each row.

Is there a simple way to perform this selection without having to mess with the dimensions too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose tensor with indicies called `idx` and have shape `(100,)`. Tensor with values called `source`. Then to select:

```
result = source[torch.arange(100), idx]
```